# Permanently rotate photos taken in portrait mode

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photos, image-editing

I have photos taken from a digital camera in which the camera was held sideways in portrait orientation.

When I view these photos in Mac Preview and Photoshop the photos show in portrait orientation as I'd like.

However, when I display these photos on a web page or upload to certain web services they are rotated to landscape orientation; the photos appear turned.

It seems that Preview and Photoshop are following some metadata to rotate the photo, but other environments are not.

How can I fix this to make the photo truly rotated?

Comment: Normally you should reduce the resolution of photos posted on the web in order to give reasonable down-load times, and I would expect an exported image to be in standard orientation (top left). I don't know that Photoshop does this, but the graphics packages I use (ACDsee and Gimp) do. If you export with the same resolution, make a copy for the other environments: recompressing a JPEG image will lose quality (if you are using a lossless format, then ignore this).

Comment: Pictures are usually rotated by using an EXIF orientation flag, not by actually moving the stored pixels around. The web sites ought to be checking this data to preserve orientation.